# How to correctly instantiate a class using @Autowired in a mapper interface in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I am currently using mapstruct to map data between entities and DTOs, inside a mapper I need to instantiate a class using @Autowired, inside the class I need to instantiate I have a method that loads data into the cache, when I try to do the following: @ Autowired RepositoryImpl repository; IntelliJ tells me: The variable 'repository' may not have been initialized. How could I use instantiate the class correctly or use the method I need?

mapper

```
@Service
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface DataMapper {

**@Autowired
RepositoryImpl repository;**

}

default DetailTemp mapDetail(String itemType, counter){

**ItemType itemType = repository.getType(itemType);**

DetailTemp detailTemp = new DetailTemp();
detailTemp.setPosition(counter);
detailTemp.setItemType(itemType);

return  DetailTemp;

}

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `@Autowire` on the interface and not the implementation?

Comment: I've been seeing that the mapper implementation classes using mapStruct are created automatically, and the logic can be used within the interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct) you need to be using an abstract class if you are using Spring components (i.e. `@Autowired RepositoryImpl repository`):

> 5.2. Inject Spring Components into the Mapper Sometimes, we'll need to utilize other Spring components inside our mapping logic. In this
> case, we have to **use an abstract class instead of an interface**:

```
 @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") public abstract class
 SimpleDestinationMapperUsingInjectedService
```

> Then, we can easily inject
> the desired component using a well-known @Autowired annotation and use
> it in our code:

```
 @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") public abstract class
 SimpleDestinationMapperUsingInjectedService {
 
     @Autowired
    protected SimpleService simpleService;
 
     @Mapping(target = "name", expression = "java(simpleService.enrichName(source.getName()))")
     public abstract SimpleDestination sourceToDestination(SimpleSource source); }
```

> We must remember not to make the injected bean private!
> This is because MapStruct has to access the object in the generated
> implementation class.